# Stripe auto-pagination with await per docs

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I'm taking a code sample directly form the Stripe docs and and in the correct environment. Why does the code sample fail?

```
// In Node 10:
for await (const customer of stripe.customers.list({limit: 3})) {
  // Do something with customer
}
```

This provides the error:

```
for await (const customer of stripe.customers.list({limit: 3})) {
    ^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word
```

Why does this code from the docs give an error, and how can it be resolved?

Comment: If you run `node --version` on your machine what version do you get? does it work if you try running inside an async function, e.g. `(async () => { /* do stuff */ })();`